# C# Any way slow down how fast HtmlWeb.Load() loads or bypass captcha?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape some web page but because HtmlWeb.Load() is so fast (I believe) it blocks me and asks me to do a captcha. Sometimes I can load it and other times I can't.

I'm wondering if there is any way to slow that down (maybe htmlweb has some built in methods/properties to do it? or maybe there's a way to limit the resources for my app so it purposely runs slow?). If that's not possible is there an easy-ish way to bypass captchas? Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
    <p>
    As you were browsing, something about your browser made us think you might be a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen, including:
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed</li>
    <li>You've disabled JavaScript and/or cookies in your web browser</li>
    <li>A third-party browser plugin is preventing JavaScript from running.</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I dont think its the loading causing the issue, but the fact that the speed at which you click/type/move/etc. is obviously fake

Comment: The whole point of a CAPTCHA is to prevent screen scraping. If there was an easy way to bypass it, it wouldn't be worth using at all, would it? And it has nothing to do with the speed with which the page loads. If the site doesn't want you doing screen scraping, you shouldn't be trying to bypass that restriction. It's most likely a violation of the terms of use of that site.

Answer (score 2):

You think it's because you're loading a single page too fast, but that's not at all what they're telling you. You're switching between pages far too quickly to be a human. And/Or, as I suspect your app may be doing, you're not loading JavaScript in your program. And/Or you're not handling cookies.

Any or all of these three things can be signs of bot activity. Which you are by the way. So they throw a captcha up because they don't want bots trying to crawl their site. You're not going to bypass captcha easily for sure, so your best bet is to address the actual issues they lay out in the message.

- Slow down the time between page loads to something more realistic for humans browsing. You might still get snagged if you're going over their entire site in a non-human fashion though.
- Handle whatever cookies they're trying to set so that you look like a normal user. A few  successive no-cookie hits to the site from the same IP might not set off a flag, but a few dozen to hundreds will.
- If those don't work, perhaps they're really insistent on JavaScript elements loading on their site, and you'll have to find a way to make your app run the JavaScript pieces so that it doesn't look like you're a bot.

But to sum it up, you're a bot, and their system is working as intended.